# VS Code input and variables don't show frequently in Interactive window

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have started using VS Code for work instead of Anaconda and there are some weird observations which I am not able to figure out.

If I try to execute some code in a cell in the interactive window, many-a-times, only output remains available and the input code automatically gets hidden. For eg. I type the following and execute:-

[image: Interactive Window Input]

And this is what I see at the window:-

[image: Interactive Window output]

Similarly, there are some variables which I have already defined but they don't show up in the Jupyer:Variables tab. For eg. there is a variable *_link_name_to_index* which is not visible in the tab as shown below:-
[image: Jupyter:Variables Tab]

However, when I execute the same in the window, I can see the values of the dictionary as expected:-
[image: Variable Output]

Maybe it is just a matter of some settings, but I still couldn't find out which one. Also, I know I have put a lot of images, because it is not a code doubt as such, rather more of a tool doubt.  I have taken only one particular example here, but I face this issue often. I am using VS Code version 1.75.0 in Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.9.12 in a virtual environment, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest Version of VSCode (1.75). It is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12743). For now, the only option seems to be downgrading to v1.74.x

Comment: Yeah even I could find only this information. I guess that's what I can do for now.